# Can`t update JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to update the frame but it doesn`t happen. How I can do it and what happens when Refresh() calls?

```
public class tttt extends JFrame{
    private JTable tab;
    private JPanel panel1;

    private void createUIComponents() {//Custom Create for tab
        Object[][] data1 =  {{'1'}};
        Object[] data2 = {'2'};
        tab = new JTable(data1, data2);
    }

    public void CreateFrame(){
        setContentPane(panel1);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void Refresh(){
        Object[][] data1 =  {{'9'}};
        Object[] data2 = {'9'};
        this.tab = new JTable(data1, data2);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tttt Frame = new tttt();//create frame with table with '1'
        Frame.CreateFrame();
        Frame.Refresh();//frame doesn`t change
    }
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: You didn't add tab to any parent component.

Comment: "Normally" you'd simply change the model data, but since you don't add it to the anything it would kind of pointless. You might also consider using a `CardLayout` to make it easier to switch between views ... if that's what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct many things in your code:

2. You need to properly create the component hierarchy and instantiate all objects in your component hierarchy. In your example, you should have JFrame -> JPanel -> JTable correctly initialized and added to the component hierarchy. Your code is not instantiating the `JPanel` named `panel1`. You will get a Null pointer exception in this line `setContentPane(panel1);`.
3. The `pack();` and `setVisible(true);` methods should be called just before you want to display your UI. They should be called after your `Refresh()` method. Again, use naming conventions to name your classes and methods correctly.

I hope this helps!

## Update:

Posting code:

```
public class tttt extends JFrame{
    private JTable tab;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JButton btnAddData;

    private void createUIComponents() {//Custom Create for tab
        Object[][] data1 =  {{'1'}};
        Object[] data2 = {'2'};
        tab = new JTable(data1, data2);
        btnAddData = new JButton("Refresh");
        
        btnAddData.addActionListener(e->Refresh());
        
        panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        panel1.add(btnAddData, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel1.add(tab, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void CreateFrame(){
        createUIComponents();
        setContentPane(panel1);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void Refresh(){
        Object[][] data1 =  {{'9'}};
        Object[] data2 = {'9'};
        tab.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data1, data2));
        revalidate();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tttt Frame = new tttt();//create frame with table with '1'
        Frame.CreateFrame();
//        Frame.Refresh();//frame doesn`t change

    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Its in separate files and it cimpiling.
2. I do hierarchy in Component Tree in Intellij IDEA

Comment: 3. Using pack(); and setVisible(true); as you say doesnt resolve my problem. And, I need to say that it's just example to simplify question. Real project is bigger and with better names.

Comment: Ok.. Thats good.. I'll update my answer. Can you consider points 2 and 3 ?

Comment: Did you check point 2? You're not initalizing the Jpanel and you are not adding the table to the jpanel

Comment: createUIComponents () call creates table, so I will not get Null pointer exception

Comment: Your code will throw NPE at this line: `setContentPane(panel1);` because you have not created your `panel1` JPanel.

Comment: And you are not adding the table to your panel.. You need to do this: `panel1.add(tab);`

Comment: Can you post code? If i just add panel1.add(tab); I get NPE

Comment: Ok, but what if I need to see the frame how it creates early and then call Refresh() (When you click a button for example)? And how I can replace new JTable in exactly the same place as the old?